# PHP Create Zip file

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to create a zip file of folder

Folder to which i want make zip is 1030
Wanted out put 1030.zip

```
$zip_file = '/var/www/html/projectnamestorage/app/public/projectname/1030.zip';
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$path = '/var/www/html/projectnamestorage/app/public/projectname/1030/originals';
$files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // We're skipping all subfolders
    if (!$file->isDir()) {
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        // extracting filename with substr/strlen
        // $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($path) + 1);
        $relativePath = 'originals/' . substr($filePath, strlen($path) + 1);
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}
$zip->close();
return response()->download($zip_file);
```

I am getting this error

ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Comment: The code looks ok, so I would start by checking privilages

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$DelFilePath = "/var/www/html/projectnamestorage/app/public/projectname/1030.zip";
if(file_exists($DelFilePath))
{
    unlink ($DelFilePath);
}
if ($zip->open($DelFilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE)
{
    die ("Could not open archive");
}
$zip->addFile("file_path","file_name");
$zip->close(); 
?>
```